# Group by pick row with lowest value (price)

Tags: mysql, group-by, min

[image]

I have all the hotel and room price, in these data, I need to fetch the lowest price room among the hotels data, below is my query it is not picking the least price example hotelname3, room2, 5.

```
SELECT *
FROM (hoteldata)
GROUP BY hotelname
ORDER BY price ASC
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving the last record in each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM hoteldata where price = (SELECT min(price) FROM hoteldata)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT hd.*
FROM (
    SELECT hotelname , MIN(price) as minprice
    FROM hoteldata
    GROUP BY hotelname
) minprices
JOIN hoteldata hd 
    ON  hd.hotelname = minprices.hotelname
    AND hd.price = minprices.minprice
```

Note: If two rooms in one hotel have the lowest price, they will be listet both.

For performance you should define an index on (*hotelname*, *price*)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/10f00/1

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM (hoteldata) order by price asc limit 1;
```

This will work for getting minimum price room from different hotel.